# How to create a switch that toggles which relationship to use?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-embedded

I want to create switch button that will be changing date (By Accounting date or by Effective date) by which report is viewed.

Currently, I have active relationship by Effective date and inactive relationship by Accounting date.

[image]

Using `USERELATIONSHIP` function I am able to bring data by both dates:

```
Total Premium by AccDate =
    CALCULATE( Sum(Premiums[Premium]),
        USERELATIONSHIP(Premiums[AccountingDate], Dates[Date]))
```

[image]

So my question, how can I place a button (switch) so end user would simply click on that button (whether effective date or accounting date) and all visuals would display data according to the switch?

Do I need to use bookmarks for that? Or there are some other tricks?

Comment: Please post some sample data and I will show you an alternative approach, very simple and without using function USERELATIONSHIP.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let's suppose you've created a new `Slicer` table to use as a slicer:

```
Type
----
Accounting Date
Effective Date
```

Using your two different premium measures,

```
Total Premium by AccDate =
    CALCULATE( Sum(Premiums[Premium]),
        USERELATIONSHIP(Premiums[AccountingDate], Dates[Date]))

Total Premium by EffDate =
    CALCULATE( Sum(Premiums[Premium]),
        USERELATIONSHIP(Premiums[EffectiveDate], Dates[Date]))
```

you can create a new measure that switches between these two based on your slicer selection:

```
Total Premium = 
    SWITCH(SELECTEDVALUE(Slicer[Type]),
           "Accounting Date", [Total Premium by AccDate],
           "Effective Date", [Total Premium by EffDate])
```

Comment: Great! Thank you Alexis!